# Creating a Lightning Aura Component - Non Coder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, developer-console

I am just trying to create a VF page where I should be get a list of related child object when i click the parent object (`Account`).

```
<aura:component controller="GetAccountAndProduct_Display__c">
  <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]" />
  <aura:attribute name="productDisplay" type="Product_Display__c[]" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
  <div>
    <div style="text-align:center;font-size:25px"> Accounts </div>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="acc">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="Adam Choi">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"
          onclick=" {!c.Clicked} "
          data-value=" {!acc.Id} " >
          {!acc.Name}
        </a>
      </div>
    </aura:iteration>
    </div>
  <div>
    <div style="text-align:center;font-size:25px"> Product_Display__c </div>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Product_Display__c}" var="con">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="Adam Choi">
        {!Product_Display__c.Name}
      </div>
    </aura:iteration>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

[image]

Can someone suggest how to remove the error. I am totally unaware I just got the coding from google and I am a non-coder. Would appreciate much If you can find the error.

Comment: where you have declare and used `foo`, `bar` attribute. put other code so we can help.

Comment: Hi Amol, I have posted my code above..Will this help

Comment: replace the `{!Product_Display__c.Name}`  to `{!con.Name}`

Comment: You say you're trying to create a Visualforce page, but this is a Lightning component. Those are entirely different, and not always compatible, technologies. Additionally, your objective sounds like it duplicates native Related List features or Lightning components. There may be more idiomatic ways to achieve your underlying objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `aura:iteration` has to have it's `items` pointing to an array - right now it's pointing to something `v.Product_Display__c` that doesn't exist.  You need to use the `v.productDisplay` variable.

Try this:

```
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.productDisplay}" var="product">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="Adam Choi">
        {!product.Name}
      </div>
    </aura:iteration>
```

Comment: That's another issue, but not the one causing this specific error.

Answer (score 4):

In Aura, you cannot use spurious spaces wherever you like. This specific error is likely from code such as:

```
      data-value=" {!acc.Id} " >
```

The extra spaces surrounding the string makes the system think you're trying to combine a string literal with a variable. This is not allowed.

Make sure you do not use extra spaces in attribute values that include merge values:

```
      data-value="{!acc.Id}">
```